# Linux/gcc: null address "00000000" with pthread  compiler option

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pthreads

I compiled a shared library with pthreads.  Why the address is "00000000" when I use pthread option to compile ? What does that mean ? Is that pthread_create is embedded into binary?

(Anyway all works as expected in both methods)

Here is the objdump output for with -lpthread

```
00000000      DF *UND*  00000aa5  GLIBC_2.1   pthread_create
```

Here is the objdump output for with -pthread

```
00000000      D  *UND*  00000000              pthread_create
```

Comment: @m0skit0 , any advantages or disadvantages for that ? . Anyway the final binary worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not relocated yet.

Usually executables on modern OS use offsets and not direct addresses. This way you can load the executable at any address, but you need to process all offsets for that. There are special sections on each executable format that indicate what and how to relocate (e.g. `.reloc` on ELF format).

More information and links on relocation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).